# Confluent Kafka configure initial connection retry timeout

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-go

I have a go project with confluent Kafka and I want to change it's initial connection timeout. If the kafka is not available on the first try I want to retry connecting to it every few seconds and give up retrying after 10 min.

By default it is repeatedly trying to connect to Kafka without break, I am getting the following log over again: `[thrd:localhost:9092/bootstrap]: localhost:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv6#[::1]:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 1ms in state CONNECT)`
(sometimes lightly different eg ipv4 instead of ipv6 and 0ms or 2ms instead of 1ms)

I've tried the following configurations but none of them seems to work

```
    conf := kafka.ConfigMap{
        "bootstrap.servers":      fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", kafkaHost, kafkaPort),
        "group.id":               "billing",
        "auto.offset.reset":      "earliest",
        "go.logs.channel.enable": true,

        "heartbeat.interval.ms":              10000,
        "session.timeout.ms":                 10000,
        "connections.max.idle.ms":            10000,
        "max.poll.interval.ms":               10000,
        "socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms": 10000,
        "auto.commit.interval.ms":            10000,
        "metadata.max.age.ms":                100000,
        "reconnect.backoff.max.ms":           100000,
        "reconnect.backoff.ms":               10000,
    }
```

I am able to connect to Kafka normally when it is running in a docker compose. Right now I only want to handle the case when it's down.

Comment: Btw, you should support a CSV list for `bootstrap.servers`, but in my experience, there isn't a wait for give up retrying connection, but your `reconnect.backoff.max.ms` is currently set to 100 seconds, not 10 minutes

Comment: I found a hacky workaround for now. I monitor connection error logs and when there are  enough of them I call `.Consumer.Close()`.